# Write to Word template from Excel crushes on the second run

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

When I open Workbook and run this code everything is fine. Also if I close Workbook and open it again and run this code everything if functioning. However if I open Workbook and try to run this code for the second time then all Word operations are crushing. Word template is opened by code and even is saved to needed destination but it is not able to close Word document and gives an error:

[image]

Is there some variable or something in Windows memory still present after code has been executed because after closing and reopening Workbook everything works fine. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Sub opentemplateWordOL()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim objWord As Object, objNewDoc As Object ''Word.Document
    Dim objOL As OLEObject
    Dim wSystem As Worksheet

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wSystem = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates")
        ''The shape holding the object from 'Create from file'
        ''Object 2 is the name of the shape
    Set sh = wSystem.Shapes("OfferLetterTemplate")
         ''The OLE Object contained
    Set objOL = sh.OLEFormat.Object
         'Instead of activating in-place, open in Word
    objOL.Verb xlOpen
    'Set objWord = objOL.Object 'The Word document

    Set objNewDoc = objOL.Object
    Set objWord = objNewDoc.Application

    Dim objUndo As Object 'Word.UndoRecord
        'Be able to undo all editing performed by the macro in one step
    Set objUndo = objWord.UndoRecord
    objUndo.StartCustomRecord "Edit In Word"

    With objNewDoc
        'Cover page
    .Bookmarks("CoverPageTitle").Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value

        objNewDoc.SaveAs2 Environ$("Temp") & "\" & _
        "MyFile" & ".docx"

        objUndo.EndCustomRecord
        objNewDoc.Undo
        .Application.Quit False

    End With
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objUndo = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
    Set wSystem = Nothing
    Set objNewDoc = Nothing

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You can check how this behaves on my computer here: https://streamable.com/2xd8k
You can see (by time of creation of file) that it is getting overwritten every time even when there is an error.

Comment: Try running using F8

Comment: Try releasing `objUndo` and `wdRng`  (`Set objUndo = Nothing : Set wdRange = Nothing`) before quitting the Word application. But note that this means you need an object variable for `objWord.Application` so that you can quit the *application* separately from the document. And then release that, as well.

Comment: @CindyMeister can you please provide some code example with this "you need an object variable" `objWord.Application`. My head does not have so much knowledge as yours yet :) What should I change in current code to achieve this?

Comment: If you use these two lines, does that make my suggestion any clearer? `Set objNewDoc = objOL.Object  : Set objWord = objNewDoc.Application` - Use one object variable for the document and a different one for the Word application. After this point, use objWord in place of where you now have objWord.Application.

Comment: @CindyMeister please see edit. Did you mean to edit current code like this?

Comment: Yes (from what I can see). This is what I had in mind. Does that work better?

Comment: @CindyMeister unfortunately same errors appear. I am working on option when Template is first downloaded from our file system to Temp folder then existing code is used partly to write, save and close it.

Comment: OK, then we need to be able to test, so it would help if you could *minimize* the code to what is only needed to reproduce the error. So change it to perhaps write one thing to the document (that doesn't rely on Excel content) and does the SaveAs. Include any steps necessary for setting this up. Then we can test and sort out where the problem is occurring.

Comment: The code runs for me without cr**a**shing, however, I did change the order of setting to Nothing - these should always be in the reverse order of how objects were instantiated (I don't *think* this is the problem, though). I note that this code does **not** work with a template in the Temp folder - it works with a template embedded in the Excel sheet. Note also that this code is always saving to the same document name. On my system, that isn't a problem. But is it possible you're getting an error about over-writing an existing file?

Comment: @CindyMeister I have added a video of running this code on my computer (it is little bit long as I don't have mouse right now, operating on laptops touch-pad =) ) I am doing exactly the same, template is embedded into Excel workbook. I have just meant I have tried another code with template in Temp folder and it works fine, without crushing. However when template is embedded into workbook, you can see result on video I have added.